# BLE gattserver with iOS

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing one app which uses bluetooth low energy for communication between device and App. My device is peripheral and App is central.While developing Android app, I have added some custom  ble services by creating gattserver on android app side and it is working ok. Now i want to achieve same thing with iOS.
My question is how to add gattserver in iOS app? Or iOS used some other procedure to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Jotunacorn for your link
This link help me to solve my issue
[Implement gattserver on iPhone](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/question/131841/how-to-setup-immediate-service-alert-client-ios/)

Answer (score 0):

I belive iOS uses the CoreBluetooth system to achive this. Check out this example
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html

There are like on Android two modes, Central and Peripheral. You want to be the in the Central mode here too. Then it should work similar to the Android GATT server.